# Birt report set table page break in script on basis of report format

Tags: birt

I am using **BIRT 4.5.** and the eclipse report design perspective

I have some reports which have tables in them.The output format of the reports is XLSX, PDF, and HTML.
Currently the page break for the tables is set to 50 and repeat header is checked.
However for only the XLSX format I want to set page break 0 and repeat header to false.

How can I do this conditionally where and what condition do I exactly need to put.Please suggest.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer for this.
In the report design perspective in eclipse click on the table in the Layout view then click on the script tab and select the onPrepare event.
Put the following script here:

```
if(reportContext.getOutputFormat()=="xlsx")
{
    reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("report_data_table").setIntProperty("pageBreakInterval",0);
    reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("report_data_table").setIntProperty("repeatHeader",false);
}
```

Replace the "report_data_table" with your table name.Hope it helps if anybody else face this issue.